# Making a bar chart in d3.js. How to put values in a single object into one bar?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to `d3.js` and I am trying to make a bar graph with an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[
    0: {potenial: 5, actual: 12, latest: 9}
    1: {potenial: 6, actual: 14, latest: 10}
    2: {potenial: 7, actual: 16, latest: 11}
    3: {potenial: 8, actual: 18, latest: 12}
    4: {potenial: 9, actual: 20, latest: 13}
]
```

And I am trying to put data of each object in a single bar. Like this:

[image]

What I've tried is:

```
// Create data array of values to visualize

var dataObj = []

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    dataObj[i] = {
        potenial: 5 + i,
        actual: 12 + (2 * i),
        latest: 9 + (i)
    }
}

console.log(dataObj)

// Create variable for the SVG
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
          .attr("height","100%")
          .attr("width","100%");

// Select, append to SVG, and add attributes to rectangles for bar chart
svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataObj)
    .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", "bar")
          .attr("height", function(d, i) {return (d.actual * 10)})
          .attr("width","40")
          .attr("x", function(d, i) {return (i * 60) + 25})
          .attr("y", function(d, i) {return 400 - (d.actual * 10)});

svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataObj)
    .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar2")
        .attr("height", function(d, i) {return (d.potenial * 10)})
        .attr("width","40")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {return (i * 60) + 25})
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {return 400 - (d.potenial * 10)});

// Select, append to SVG, and add attributes to text
svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(dataObj)
    .enter().append("text")
    .text(function(d) {return d.actual})
           .attr("class", "text")
           .attr("x", function(d, i) {return (i * 60) + 36})
           .attr("y", function(d, i) {return 415 - (d.actual * 10)});
```

This gave me:

[image]

So, I just did the same thing for the `potential` values as I did for `actual` values. But only one shows up.

What do I have to do differently for different values?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

```
svg.selectAll("text2")
    .data(dataObj)
    .enter().append("text2")
    .text(function(d) {return d.potenial})
           .attr("class", "text2")
           .attr("x", function(d, i) {return (i * 60) + 36})
           .attr("y", function(d, i) {return 415 - (d.potenial * 10)});
```

Comment: it doesn't tell me how to do it, and i want them to overlap rather than being stacked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nvd3 Stacked Bar Chart with discrete values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203404/nvd3-stacked-bar-chart-with-discrete-values)

Comment: I think you could have a look at the Grouped Bar Chart https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051. You have identical `x` value calculation, you will not see the individual bars. You don't fill them differently either.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the second `svg.selectAll("rect")`.  This is selecting the initially added `.bar` rects, replacing their data, then calculating an **empty** `.enter` selection and not appending anything.  If you want the two sets of `rect` to be independent then use a different `.selectAll`.  I always try to do it by class.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .bar {
        fill: steelblue;
      }
      
      .bar2 {
        fill: orange;
      }
      
      body {
        width: 800px;
        height: 800px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      var dataObj = []

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    dataObj[i] = {
        potenial: 5 + i,
        actual: 12 + (2 * i),
        latest: 9 + (i)
    }
}

console.log(dataObj)

// Create variable for the SVG
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
          .attr("height","100%")
          .attr("width","100%");

// Select, append to SVG, and add attributes to rectangles for bar chart
svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(dataObj)
    .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", "bar")
          .attr("height", function(d, i) {return (d.actual * 10)})
          .attr("width","40")
          .attr("x", function(d, i) {return (i * 60) + 25})
          .attr("y", function(d, i) {return 400 - (d.actual * 10)});

svg.selectAll(".bar2")
    .data(dataObj)
    .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar2")
        .attr("height", function(d, i) {return (d.potenial * 10)})
        .attr("width","40")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {return (i * 60) + 25})
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {return 400 - (d.potenial * 10)});

// Select, append to SVG, and add attributes to text
svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(dataObj)
    .enter().append("text")
    .text(function(d) {return d.actual})
           .attr("class", "text")
           .attr("x", function(d, i) {return (i * 60) + 36})
           .attr("y", function(d, i) {return 415 - (d.actual * 10)});
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks! One thing is, are the graphs stacked, or is the yellow bar graph just overlapping with the blue graph? Also, how can I make the value of `potential` to show up on the tip of the yellow bar? Thanks again. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: So, it seems like it's not a stack and it just overlaps, so thats great. If you see my edit, that what I've tried to add text to the yellow bar, but it doesn't show up.